# Under what conditions can an operator be moved under the integral

Tags: integration, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and suppose $G=\{U(\alpha) \}_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}} $ is one parameter group of linear bounded maps $U(\alpha):\mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$ under composition such that $U(0)=Id $. Now suppose that for a fixed $\psi\in \mathcal{H}$ we define $A_\psi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathcal{H}$ as $$\tau \mapsto \int_0^\tau U(\alpha)\psi  \;d\alpha $$
My question is: Under what conditions does the following equation holds? for any $\epsilon\in \mathbb{R}$
$$\bigr(U(\epsilon )\circ A_{\psi}\bigr)(\tau)= \int_0^\tau U(\epsilon)\cdot U(\alpha)\psi\; d\alpha $$

Here I used the notation $U(\epsilon)\cdot U(\alpha)\psi\equiv \bigr(U(\epsilon) \circ U(\alpha)\bigr)(\psi)$

Comment: There are different notions of intergability for vector valued functions. Is your integral defining $A_{\psi}$ a Pettis integral or  a Bochner intergal?

Comment: In both cases the operator can be moved inside but the proof differs. No  extra conditions necessary.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I meant the Bochner integral, thanks for pointing that out. Regarding your last comment can you give reference or please provide a sketch of the proof?

Comment: Vector Measures  by Diestel and Uhl is a good reference for this.

Comment: I think $U(\alpha)$ needs some regularity in $\alpha$.  If that is part of the definition of "one parameter group" you could say so.